# Why I'm getting the error message: Unable to get a routing table for database

Tags: python, python-3.x, neo4j

I'm trying to build simple database in neo4j and check if node exists.

I wrote a simple code:

```
def find_and_return_person(tx, person_name):
    query = (
        "MATCH (p:Person) "
        "WHERE p.name = $person_name "
        "RETURN p.name AS name"
    )
    result = tx.run(query, person_name=person_name)
    return [record["name"] for record in result]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    scheme = "neo4j"
    host_name = "localhost"
    port = 7687
    url = "{scheme}://{host_name}:{port}".format(scheme=scheme, host_name=host_name, port=port)
    user = "neo4j"
    password = "s3cr3t"
    driver = GraphDatabase.driver(url, auth=(user, password))
    session = driver.session(database="foo")
    result = session.read_transaction(find_and_return_person, "Alice")
```

But I'm getting error:

```
neo4j.exceptions.ClientError: {code: Neo.ClientError.Database.DatabaseNotFound} {message: Unable to get a routing table for database 'foo' because this database does not exist}
```

What is wrong ? (I created a new session named "foo") so what it missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want to use the "system" or "neo4j" databases, you need to [create a database](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.1/administration/databases/#administration-databases-create-database) before trying to use it.